# Group nested list with linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I have a nested list of objects. That I need to group by `identifierA` and `Sum` its numeric properties, nested list shall group respectively:

```
public class TypeA
{
    public String identifierA{ get; set; }
    public Int32 number { get; set; }
    public List<TypeB> nestedList { get; set; }
}
public class TypeB
{
    public String identifierB { get; set; }
    public Int32 otherNumber { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm expecting something like this:

```
var List<TypeA> groupedList = (from a in TypeAList
                               group a by a.identifierA
                               into groupedData
                               select new TypeA
                               {
                                   identifierA = groupedData.Key,
                                   number = groupedData.Sum(g => g.number ),
                                   nestedList = //HOW TO GROUP NESTED PART?
                               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Question is unclear. What you want to do here "nestedList = //HOW TO SUM/GROUP NESTED PART?"

Comment: I meant Group and sum the numeric part of TypeB as well. But you are right - not very clear, didn't know how to formulate it properly. Changed it to just grouped.

Comment: Are you need to group nested part by identifierB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this  will resolve your issue.

```
List<TypeA> list = TypeAList
    .GroupBy(a => a.identifierA)
    .Select(
        g =>
        new TypeA
            {
                identifierA = g.Key,
                number = g.Sum(n => n.number),
                nestedList =
                    g.SelectMany(l => l.nestedList)
                    .GroupBy(b => b.identifierB)
                    .Select(
                        gg =>
                        new TypeB
                            {
                                identifierB = gg.Key,
                                otherNumber = gg.Sum(b => b.otherNumber)
                            }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, that's the one, Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

`SelectMany` takes an `IEnumerable<SomethingWithAnIEnumerable>` and flattens all the `SomethingWithAnIEnumerable`'s selected `IEnumerable`s into a single `IEnumerable`:

```
nestedList = groupedData.SelectMany(pa => pa.nestedList).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

if you want to group the list into one use

```
nestedList = groupedData.SelectMany(d=>d.nestedList)
```

and if you want `Sum` of that list, use

```
nestedList = groupedData.SelectMany(d=>d.nestedList).Sum(o=>o.otherNumber)
```

Comment: I think the `Sum` part is wrong here. I admit that the question is not exactly clear since the OP said *HOW TO SUM/GROUP NESTED PART?*, but `TypeA.nestedList` is of type `List<TypeB>` and not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your IdentfierB might be a key of some kind, and your result should reflect Grouped and Summed TypeBs.

```
List<TypeA> groupedList = TypeAList
  .GroupBy(a => a.identifierA)
  .Select(g => new TypeA()
  {
    identierA = g.Key,
    number = g.Sum(a => a.number)
    nestedList = g.SelectMany(a => a.nestedList)
      .GroupBy(b => b.identifierB)
      .Select(g2 => new TypeB()
      {
        identifierB = g2.Key,
        otherNumber = g2.Sum(b => b.otherNumber)
      }
  }
```