# List order by another contained list

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a list of Objects and one of the item is another list. How can I Group them based on the inner list. 
Here is an example of what I wish to do.

```
class Student
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public List<GroupInfo> GroupList; // This is the inner list
}

class GroupInfo
{
    public string GroupName;
    public int GroupId;
}

static void Main() 
{
   GroupInfo firstGroup = new GroupInfo
   {
      GroupId = 1,
      GroupName = "First group"
   };

   GroupInfo secondGroup = new GroupInfo
   {
       GroupId = 2,
       GroupName = "Second group"
    };

    GroupInfo thirdGroup = new GroupInfo
    {
       GroupId = 3,
       GroupName = "Third group"
    };

    GroupInfo fourthGroup = new GroupInfo
    {
       GroupId = 4,
       GroupName = "Fourth group"
    };

    List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

    Student firstStudent = new Student();
    firstStudent.Name = "Name1";
    firstStudent.Age = 15;
    firstStudent.GroupList = new List<GroupInfo>();
    firstStudent.GroupList.Add(firstGroup);
    firstStudent.GroupList.Add(secondGroup);
    studentList.Add(firstStudent);

    Student secondStudent = new Student();
    secondStudent.Name = "Name2";
    secondStudent.Age = 17;
    secondStudent.GroupList = new List<GroupInfo>();
    secondStudent.GroupList.Add(firstGroup);
    secondStudent.GroupList.Add(thirdGroup);
    studentList.Add(secondStudent);

    Student thirdStudent = new Student();
    thirdStudent.Name = "Name3";
    thirdStudent.Age = 18;
    thirdStudent.GroupList = new List<GroupInfo>();
    thirdStudent.GroupList.Add(secondGroup);
    thirdStudent.GroupList.Add(thirdGroup);
    thirdStudent.GroupList.Add(fourthGroup);
    studentList.Add(thirdStudent);

    List<GroupInfo> groupInfoList = new List<GroupInfo>();
   // Now What I want is to get a group List Where...
    foreach (var student in studentList)
    {
        // ...First Group Should contains firstStudent and secondStudent
        // Second group Should firstStudent & thirdStudent
        // Third group Should contains secondStudent & thirdStuden
        // Fourth Group Should contains only thirdStudent
      }
    }
```

One way is to iterate on the whole List and populate the GroupInfo List. Just wondering is there any other way to do this task.

Comment: look at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747344/group-nested-list-with-linq

Comment: Something like that will do the trick:
var groupedStudents = 
                studentList.SelectMany(x => x.GroupList, (student, groupInfo) => new {Student = student, Group = groupInfo})
                .GroupBy(x => x.Group);
But I guess what you really want is too add a relation between groups and students? So when you're adding group to the student's group list, this student should be added in group's students list and visa versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) like this:-

```
var result = studentList.SelectMany(x => x.GroupList, 
                                      (studentObj, groups) => new { studentObj, groups })
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.groups.GroupId, x.groups.GroupName })
                        .Select(x => new 
                               {
                                  GroupId = x.Key.GroupId,
                                  GroupName = x.Key.GroupName,
                                  Students = x.Select(z => z.studentObj).ToList()
                               });
```

Since your `GroupInfo` class only has two properties i.e. `GroupId` & `GroupName`, you won't be able to fetch the Students associated with it. This is the reason I am fetching anonymous type out of it.

I am getting following output with this query:-

[image]

Comment: Perfect, as i wanted Rahul. Many Thanks.