# Group by clause inside a nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to apply group by clause to a list element inside a parent list. How can I skip looping and write this within a single linq query

```
foreach (var record in marketRecordDTOs)
{                   
    record.Sources = record.Sources
                        .GroupBy(i => i.SourceId)
                        .Select(i => i.FirstOrDefault())
                        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Group nested list with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13759227/2417602).

Comment: You can use `ForEach` or `Select` (change and return the same object), but I don't personally think it would look better. Why don't you like `foreach`?

Comment: You are _modifying_ the `Sources` of each record. But the Q in LINQ stands for **query**, not modifying. LINQ is _not_ for modifying data, but querying.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Nothing like I hate for each . I am just looking at the possibilities for making code shorter .

Comment: @RenéVogt I understand that . I can take the grouped query to a temporary list and assign it back .

Answer (score 0):

So you can easily create an `IEnumerable<>` of all your new `Sources`:

```
var newSources = marketRecordDTOs.Select(record => record.Sources
                                                         .GroupBy(i => i.SourceId)
                                                         .Select(i => i.FirstOrDefault())
                                                         .ToList()
                                        );
```

Though, I am not sure what you intend to do with it after that.